# Edit distance, with a twist

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve something using dynamic programming, but I'm having some trouble. When I work on dynamic programming, I usually determine a recursive algorithm then go from there to my dynamic solution. This time I'm having trouble

**The Problem**

Say you have two strings: m and n, such that n.length is greater than m.length, and n does not contain the character '#'. You want the string that turns m into the same length as string n in minimum cost.

Cost is defined as SUM(Penalty(m[i],n[i])), where i is in an index of the strings char array.

Penalty is defined as such

```
private static int penalty(char x,char y) {
    if (x==y) { return 0;}
    else if (y=='#') { return 4;}
    else { return 2;}
}
```

The only way I can think of is as follows:

[0] If m and n are the same length, return m

[1] Compute cost of inserting a # at any index of m

[2] determine the string that has the minimum of such cost. Let that string be m'

[3] Run the algorithm on m' and n again.

I don't think this is even the optimal recursive algorithm, leading me to believe that I'm not on the right track for a dynamic algorithm.

I've read up on using a m.length x n.length matrix for normal edit distance, but I don't see how I could easily transform that to fit my algorithm.

Thoughts on my recursive algorithm and the steps I need to take to reach a dynamic solution?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your definitions (python):

```
def penalty(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return 0
    if y == '#':
        return 4
    return 2

def cost(n, m):
    return sum(penalty(a, b) for a, b in zip(n, m))
```

Then you can define the distance reassigning to `m` the lowest cost for each `#` to be included.

```
def distance(n, m):
    for _ in range(len(n) - len(m)):
        m = min((m[:i]+'#'+m[i:] for i in range(len(m)+1)), key=lambda s: cost(n, s))
    return m

>>> distance('hello world', 'heloworld')
'he#lo#world'
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see the optimality principle to work here is if you solve the problem over growing lengths of `n`. So the dynamic programming solution would look like this:

1. For each contiguous substring of length `m.length()+1`, solve the problem, yielding a list of proposals for the new `m`.
2. Select the proposal with the minimum distance to the corresponding substring as the new `m`, and repeat the process.

You won't need to store anything other than the currently optimal solution in this algorithm, certainly not a distance matrix. It looks to me like you were pretty close to this solution as well, you only missed the 'shrink `n` to get a subproblem'-part.